how to reach path in flutter web using filepicker
Im making a flutter web app where i can upload data from csv by clicking a button and using filepicker, originally this code is from an android app
 onPressed: () async {
        ArchivoController archivito = ArchivoController();
        print('presionado');
        await archivito.abrircsv();
        
      },

my problem is when im uploading data from an utf-8 csv issued by excel, first when entering leerCSV the debug console throws that path is unavailable in flutter web, and should be using bytes instead, but bytes itself is Uint8list and File needs a String
 final input = File(archivo!.files.single.path!).openRead();

so i tried to use toString() method, but it froze and doesnt continue
  final input = File(archivo!.files.single.bytes!.toString()).openRead();

i tried to cast it as String but the console output is:
Error al leer el archivo CSV: TypeError: Instance of 'NativeUint8List': type 'NativeUint8List' is not a subtype of type 'String'

I want to know a way to get the path, like in mobile but for a web app
My goal is to reach the path of the file, because i need to know where it is in order to read it and upload the info to firestore
My class:
class ArchivoController {
  FilePickerResult? archivo;
  Map<String, List<String>> inventarioMap = {};

  Future<void> abrircsv() async {
    try {
      archivo = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.any,
        // allowedExtensions: ['csv'],
        allowMultiple: false,
        // initialDirectory: '/storage/emulated/0/Download',
        // withData: true,
      );
      //imprimir nombre del archivo
      // print(archivo!.files.single.name);
      leerCSV();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error al seleccionar archivos: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> leerCSV() async {
    if (archivo != null) {
      try {
        // Lee el archivo CSV como texto
        // final fileBytes =  archivo!.files.first.bytes;
        // final fileName = archivo!.files.first.name;
        final input = File(archivo!.files.single.bytes!).openRead();
        print('realizando lectura...');
        final fields = await input
            .transform(utf8
                .decoder) //es por esta instrucción que se debe guardar el archivo como UTF-8 CSV
            .transform(const CsvToListConverter())
            .toList();
        print('Lectura realizada...');
        print('revisando campos');
        if (fields.isNotEmpty) {
          print('definiendo header y contenido del csv...');
          List<String> headers = fields[0].cast<String>();
          List<Map<String, dynamic>> csvData = [];
          print('Llenando mapa con datos del csv...');
          // Llena el mapa con los datos del CSV
          for (var i = 1; i < fields.length; i++) {
            Map<String, dynamic> row =
                {}; // se inicializa cada que pasa una fila nueva
            for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
              row[headers[j]] = fields[i][j];
            }
            csvData.add(row);
            // print(row);
          }
          print('Leido por completo subiendo a firestore...');
          await subirDatosAFirestore(csvData);
        } else {
          print("El archivo CSV está vacío.");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error al leer el archivo CSV: $e");
      }
    } else {
      print("No se seleccionó ningún archivo.");
    }
  }


You're already using csv package right?

use XFile.openRead instead of File.openRead

thank you but my new question is how to reach the path of a file in flutter web like in mobile

you need a Stream, so instead of final input = File(archivo!.files.single.bytes!).openRead(); which returns Stream<List<int>> you should use XFile.openRead() which returns the stream you need
